# I/O bound processes over CPU bound processes

Tags: operating-systems, process-scheduling

will an OS which favors I/O bound processes over CPU-Bound processes, experience less average waiting time? If yes, why?

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  What are your thoughts?  What reading and self-study have you done?  How have you tried to reason through this?  We're happy to help you understand concepts, but just solving exercise-style problems for you is unlikely to achieve that.  The purpose of exercises is to prompt you to spend some time thinking for yourself, and asking others to solve them for you may defeat the purpose.  See also http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755.

Comment: Cross-posted: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/66847/755, http://stackoverflow.com/q/40946169/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.  And if you are copying from others, make sure to [attribute your sources](http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).

Answer (score 2):

Take a sheet of paper.

Assume you have one process that uses an I/O device for 5ms, then the CPU for 5ms, and so on, a total of one million times (5000 seconds I/O, 5000 seconds CPU). Assume another process uses the CPU for 5000 seconds.

Using that sheet of paper, check the progress of both processes if (1) process A is given higher CPU priority, (2) process B is given higher CPU priority, (3) both are given equal priority.

Answer (score 0):

As a first year studen I was pretty sure it was CPU-bound that was the right answer as that silly I/O could wait, my calculations were more important.

As a second year student I was convinced that it was the I/O bound that should be prioritized because of the longer latencies.

Later I would calculate with O(X) and determine the "right" answer.

Now many years later I would say you have to measure it for your specific setup.